# Add an additional validation condition and show an error if needed

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have the following code in a controller:

```
  val addForm = Form(
    tuple("email" -> nonEmptyText, "password" -> nonEmptyText)
  )

  def add = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.registration.add(addForm))
  }

  def create = Action { implicit request =>
    addForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      failure => //....,
      success => //....
```

At `create` (? or anywhere else it makes sense) method I want to check some additional conditions, for example, whether an email already exists in a db. And if it does, return an error to a view says "this email already exists".

I didn't find anything about it at the Play's documentation, only about the standard restrictions like "nonEmpty".

Where and how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import play.api.data.Mapping
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.data.validation._

val addForm = Form(
  tuple("email" -> freeEmail, "password" -> nonEmptyText)
)

def freeEmail: Mapping[String] = {
  nonEmptyText verifying Constraint[String]("constraint.email") { o: String =>
    if (Email.exists(o) /*your checker here*/) Invalid(ValidationError("Email already exists")) else Valid
  }
}
```

Comment: is "constraint.email" related to a table? What if I don't have such a constraint in my table?

Comment: No, it is related to message localization. If you have a `messages.en` file in your `/conf` folder then you may write something like this: `constraint.email="Email already exists"`